# Будут ли работать мои программы и скрипты после переустановки windows?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, windows-7

У меня есть программа написанная на python.Она представляет собой несколько файлов .py с кодом, запускается через бат файл.Хочу с помощью переустановки перейти с windows 7 на windows 10.Будет ли моя программа работать на новой винде если я сохраню ее к примеру на флешке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от списка установленных библиотек для питон, их версий и привередливости ваших скриптов к конкретным версиям библиотек. Если скрипты не привередливые, достаточно будет установить текущие (последнии) версии библиотек, но случается что какой-то библиотеки нет для более новой версии python (или нет в pip, или нет для нужной архитектуры процессора (x86/x64/arm/...), или она была переименована...), и приходится собирать ее самому или переходить на более старый питон.

Часть библиотек могла быть установлена не через общий репозиторий pip, а, например, при установке пакетов программ в качестве их интерфейса к питону...

получить список установленных библиотек можно из командной строки:

```
python -m pip list
```

текущая версия питона:

```
python --version
```

Стоит запомнить выдачу этих команд и записать на флешку.
Стоит, также, сохранить всю папку python (ее можно использовать для извлечения бинарных пакетов в самом тяжелом случае). Если используется виртуальное окружения (т.е. есть папки .venv / .virtualenvs / .conda /... рядом с папкой ваших скриптов, или в папке локального пользователя) их тоже сохраните.

Хотя, часто случается, что большинство установленных библиотек не используются конкретным скриптом. Имеет смысл устанавливать библиотеки по одной, анализируя сообщения об ошибках при запуске скриптов. Если этот путь не приведет к успеху, сначала откатываемся к тем же версиям библиотек, что были установлены на исходной машине, или сразу и к той-же версии python, но это самый крайний случай.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ.Самое главное что бы код не пришлось писать заново.Как я понял если я сохраню на флешке программу, то код и базу данных(.db файл) я не потеряю, верно?

Comment: Очевидно, все файлы баз данных, картинок, текстовых справочников, настроек, и т.д. нужно сохранить вместе с программой. Они могут лежать не только в папке программы, но и в папках пользователя (в "моих документах", например). Какие сторонние файлы программа использует, знает только автор программы. Хотя хорошие авторы, стараются хранить данные так, чтобы место хранения было очевидно для пользователя, но получается не всегда. Если возможно, обратитесь к автору программы. Вообще, сохранить всю папку users не помешает.

Comment: Автор программы я.Мне важно было знать, не потеряю ли я возможность пользоваться программой.Вопрос решен, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Установи только Python после переустановки системы, если вдруг не заработает, включи режим совместимости с Win7 с свойствах батника.